# Algebra help, complex numbers and sine

Tags: complex-numbers

I have

$$ x = 1-\frac{p}{2}(e^{iw}-e^{-iw}) + \frac{p^2}{2}( e^{iw} -2 + e^{-iw}) $$

$$ x = 1- \frac{p}{2}(2 i \sin w)   +\frac{p^2}{2}(-4\sin^{2}\frac{w}{2}) $$

$$ |x^{2}|  = ( 1 - ip\sin w -2p^{2}\sin^2{w/2}) (   1 + ip\sin w -2p^{2}\sin^2{w/2} )         $$

after doing all the algebra i get

$$ 1 + p^{2} \sin^{2}w - 4p^{2}\sin^{2}w/2 + 4p^{4}\sin^{4}w/2$$

but the correct answer is

$$1 + 4p^{2}(p^2-1)\sin^{4}w/2$$

which i can seem to get, can anyone show me how? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Isn't there an error in the last term of the first line?

Comment: if you asking about the omega term i fixed it

Comment: I also wondered  whether it was actually the expansion of $(e^{iw}-e^{-iw})^2$?

Comment: yes its the modulus squared

Comment: It looks like you did everything correctly.... In the picture, do those brackets $[e^{i\omega}-e^{-i\omega}]$ mean anything other than parentheses? Perhaps "Real part"?

Comment: Well the modulus squared isn't the same thing as the square.

Comment: i edited it, i forgot to include the modulus.

Comment: Interpreting $[u]$ as $\text{Re}(u)$ seems to give the correct result*, but it doesn't make sense; $\xi$ would be Real then. *No, it would have $\sin^2$ instead of $\sin^4$.

Comment: the brackets dont mean anything, i am sure it some trick with sines and cosines which i cant figure out !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-angle identity:

$$\sin 2\theta = 2\sin\theta\cos\theta$$

$$\sin\omega = 2\sin\frac\omega2\cos\frac\omega2$$

$$\sin^2\omega = 4\sin^2\frac\omega2\cos^2\frac\omega2$$

$$\sin^2\omega-4\sin^2\frac\omega2 = 4\sin^2\frac\omega2\Big(\cos^2\frac\omega2-1\Big) = 4\sin^2\frac\omega2\Big(-\sin^2\frac\omega2\Big) = -4\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

Therefore

$$1+p^2\sin^2\omega-4p^2\sin^2\frac\omega2+4p^4\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

$$= 1+p^2\Big(\sin^2\omega-4\sin^2\frac\omega2\Big)+4p^4\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

$$= 1+p^2\Big(-4\sin^4\frac\omega2\Big)+4p^4\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

$$= 1+\big(-4p^2+4p^4\big)\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

$$= 1+4p^2(p^2-1)\sin^4\frac\omega2$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don’t understand the last line

Comment: I added a step in between. Do you follow?

Comment: Yes thank you so much!